# A deployment of an application iOS on a development device, has validity?

Tags: ios, deployment, app-store, ipa, ios-provisioning

Can expire the validity a deployment in an app iOS from the development device? (iOS Developer Program)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the certificate expires on the device, the app will no longer launch.